# Where to setAdapter in AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to improve the performance of my mobile App. I'm attempting to use AsyncTask. I've looked at quite a lot of documentation on AsyncTask, also looked at numerous questions on here, but can't seem to get my code to run correctly.

I've seen examples where the Adapter is set in the onPostExecute method, but that does not work for me..

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_travel_updates);



        Twitter.initialize(this);

        new getTweets().execute();
    }


private class getTweets extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(travel_updates.this));
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        final UserTimeline searchTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder().screenName("TflTravelAlerts")
                .maxItemsPerRequest(5)
                .build();

        final TweetTimelineRecyclerViewAdapter tweetAdapter =
                new TweetTimelineRecyclerViewAdapter.Builder(travel_updates.this)
                        .setTimeline(searchTimeline)
                        .setViewStyle(R.style.tw__TweetLightWithActionsStyle)
                        .build();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void Void) {

recyclerView.setAdapter(tweetAdapter);

    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: *"but that does not work for me.."* Can you explain this a little better for us to help you?

Comment: Yes! apologies for my vague description!  The error received is "cannot resolve symbol 'recyclerView'"

Comment: It's declared in a different method. Assuming this is all one class, declare and initialize that stuff in `onCreate()` then set the adapter as you are now.

Comment: Yes all in the main class... Thanks i'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your `RecycleView` in your MainActivity not in the `onPreExecute` method of your `AsyncTask`.

With in your `onCreate` method you can set the `RecyclerView`.

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_travel_updates);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(travel_updates.this));

    Twitter.initialize(this);

    new getTweets().execute();
}
```

Because you have `UserTimeline` and `TweetTimelineRecyclerViewAdapter` inside the `doInBackground` method (which is not on the same Thread as you UI) you cannot set the adapter in `doInBackground`. Set the adapter on the UI thread.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    final UserTimeline searchTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder().screenName("TflTravelAlerts")
            .maxItemsPerRequest(5)
            .build();

    final TweetTimelineRecyclerViewAdapter tweetAdapter =
            new TweetTimelineRecyclerViewAdapter.Builder(travel_updates.this)
                    .setTimeline(searchTimeline)
                    .setViewStyle(R.style.tw__TweetLightWithActionsStyle)
                    .build();

     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recyclerView.setAdapter(tweetAdapter);
    });

    // I don't think you need to return anything if your method uses void??
    return null;
}
```

Then  `onPostExecute` should be empty.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense now..  AsyncTask is new to me.

Comment: @AaronStrickland :: I have never used `UserTimeline` or `TweetTimelineRecyclerViewAdapter` So I don't what options you have about retrieving data and in what types are available (String, int, float...). Usually, you can pass those values to the `onPostExecute` method. The `onPostExecute` method does work on the UI Thread.